# C++ program triggers Norton SONAR.Heuristic.170

Tags: c++, norton

I'm developing a C++ program in Visual C++ 2010 Express. Everytime I rebuild, and run, I get a warining Norton on thread *SONAR.Heuristic.170*.

It reports network activity from source file link.exe on my *file created* myprog.exe

My program does not do any network activity I'd be aware of.

Any ideas, where this is coming from?

~~~~~~~~~~ 
refining the question:

- program links to libmysql.dll and establishes a database connection to localhost on port 3306; assume that's what Norton picks up as network activity.
- seems that the heuristic is then triggered by (1) program with very few users (obviously - only me), (2) program new (obviously - just compiled) and (3) network activity (to localhost)

Is this a correct set of assumptions?
Any way to suppress this warning?

Comment: It can be a false positive, when some part of your code looks like a virus signature.